# Efeito de expansão de navbar no angular

Tags: html, css, angular

Estou tentando fazer um efeito de expansão de navbar no angular.

Quando clicar no link "mostrar informações" o conteúdo deve subir, e quando clicar em "ocultar", o conteúdo deve abaixar.

O problema é que a parte superior do meu footer não está acompanhando o efeito de expansão.

Tentei algo como:

```
<footer class="page-footer font-small footer-fundo-cinza">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row pt-3">
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="../../../assets/estilomotocar-rodape.png" class="img-responsive img-fluid">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div [@fadeInUpDown]="mostrar_informacoes" [@statusDisplay]="mostrar_informacoes" class="row">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <hr>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</footer>
```

Minhas animações:

```
export const statusDisplay =

    trigger('statusDisplay', [
        state('aberto',  style({ display: 'block' })),
        state('fechado', style({ display: 'none'  })),
        transition('fechado => aberto', animate('0ms ease')),
        transition('aberto => fechado', animate('0ms 200ms ease'))
    ])


export const fadeInUpDown =

    trigger('fadeInUpDown', [
        state('fechado', style({
            transform: 'translate3d(0,100%,0)'
        })),
        state('aberto', style({
            transform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)'
        })),
        transition('fechado <=> aberto', animate('400ms ease'))
    ])
```

Se eu colocar minha animação fadeInUpDown direto no meu footer o efeito funciona como esperado, porém ele aplica o translate3d no início empurrando pra fora da página, habilitando um scroll.

Meu css:

```
 footer{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
```